# How can I execute curl command in PowerShell to download files from JFrog Artifactory without invoking cmd.exe?

Tags: powershell, cmd, artifactory

The below command I am using in PowerShell which invokes cmd.exe

```
cmd.exe /c curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: <API key>" "<ARTIFACTORY_URL>" -o "<Local_Path>
```

Comment: Change `cmd.exe /c curl` to `curl.exe`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I googled powershell curl and got this https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl telling me about `Invoke-RestMethod`

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid `curl` is alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` in PowerShell

Comment: So why not use it?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thats what the whole query is about  , Can you help me with syntax in Power Shell

Comment: Well here's one example of syntax. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1#example-1--send-a-web-request Please try something and then ask a question when you have an issue

Answer (score 2):

JFrog has its own CLI called JFrog CLI. It is a compact and smart client that provides a simple interface that automates access to JFrog products simplifying your automation scripts making them more readable and easier to maintain.

In your case, download from Artifactory is one of its commands.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry20qKqJzys) is a short video for you to get started with JFrog CLI.

Comment: Hi @Or-G I want  to do this in Power shell Since my its a part of my Script

Comment: @RajM, you can run JFrog CLI within Powershell, just make sure it is included inside PATH env var.

Comment: Were you able to do it in powershell, can you show how you did it? i am in the same boat